Blazor PWA opens all links in inapp browser
If I publish this Blazor PWA (without any changes) and publish it to my Azure App Service, and then add it to the homescreen all links in the app opens in the "app":
https://github.com/Piotr1215/pwa-sample

If I start a new Blazor PWA project in Visual Studio 2022 (.NET 8) and publish it to an App Service, all links in the app, opens in a "inapp browser", like the image below, even though it's internal links:

(I have to add this to index.html to get the app to actually open as an app instead of in Safari, but that's all I change:
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent">

I've compared the two projects, but can't figure out why. Anyone who has experienced the same thing?

Can you elaborate more on the difference between the two projects?  It's not very clear from the question.

For instance the .net versioons.

The PWA-SampleApp:

netstandard2.1
3.0
service-worker-
assets.js

The project template in Visual Studio:

net8.0
enable
enable
service-worker-
assets.js


That's it. Index.html, service-worker and manifest is the same. My main question is if someone else has experienced the same behaviour with the project template in Visual Studio.
